# sqlite3: retrieving data based on month and year from local database in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

In my application I have to store data month wise and year wise. So for this, I have to store the data along with date into database.

My requirement is how to store in terms of date and how to retrieve data with group by month and year. In my app I am showing a table of years and months, based on selected month and year. I have to show the data in a dashboard.

My problem is in storing and retrieving date data types.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax

```
SELECT * FROM DATABASE WHERE REQUIREDDATEFIELD LIKE '%2011-01%';
```

2011 is supposed to be the year

01 is supposed to be the month

DATABASE is supposed to be your mysql database name

REQUIREDDATEFIELD is supposed to be the field you are hoping to sort from month and year.

like '%2011-01%' is supposed to be meaning, all the records containing 2011-01 in the given field. It could be in the beginning or the end or in the middle of a large text, so having % in both the beginning and end of the search criteria is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

You just select either for a specific month or year or month and year. Or if you want all, you use GROUP BY.

I know this answer is quite vague and generic, but that's because your question is vague. You probably need to be more specific. Explain not only what you want to do, but what you have tried, and in which way that didn't work.

Comment: i am not satisified with your answer . what i am expecting is i want to save data as 01-07-2011 , 2000 , fees  .it is a row of my table.When ever i want to retrive for jan of 2011 this data should come .i want the query what we have to use to retrieve from database that should work with sqlite3 and objective c code kk

Comment: @Ramesh India: You aren't satisfied because your question is so vague, that I have to give a vague answer. I repeat: **Explain not only what you want to do, but what you have tried, and in which way that didn't work.**